# 301 redirect for a page with a space in it

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I have some pages from a client's old template-based site which have spaces in them.  For example, one of the pages looks like this:

```
example.com/page.php?domain_name=example.com&viewpage=Gallery %26 News
```

I'm thinking that the correct way to do an htaccess 301 redirect is to include something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /page.php?domain_name=example.com&viewpage=Gallery%20%26%20News http://www.example.com/gallery/
```

where the new page is:

```
example.com/gallery
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL path for the mod_alias `Redirect` should be %-decoded. If it contains spaces then surround the path in double quotes:

```
Redirect 301 "/page.php?domain_name=example.com&viewpage=Gallery & News" http://www.example.com/gallery/
```